# Backgroundworker ReportProgress only triggered once?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

What could the reason be that my `Processbar1` and `ReportProgress` respectively, only gets triggered once?

First time I click the button everything is working as it was expected. All further Clicks every thing is still working, except the `ProgressBar1`!

I can see in the debugger that `progressBar1.Value` get the expected values in the first run, all further runs `progressBar1.Value` always contains "0".

It's most odd that it runs the `foreach-loop`, all stuff are executed, even the values in the `b.ReportProgress(i * 100 / x)` are correctly, but no successful progressbar.
*i= current loop count

 x= total loop count*
.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
BackgroundWorker b = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(b_DoWork);
        b.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(b_RunWorkerCompleted);
        b.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(b_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void b_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int x = xxx.MaxValue;
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            //... somecode   ...(item);
            b.ReportProgress(i * 100 / x);
            i++;
        }
        //... somecode
        e.Result = dt;
    }

    void b_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void b_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.DataSource = e.Result;
        GridView.Update();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
    private void btnClearGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Clear();
        GridView.DataSource = dt;
        GridView.Update();
    }
```

I've found the problem..
The problem was that I tried to clear the Gridview before I run the Backgroundworker and this `btnClearGrid`-Click-Event, which contains `GridView.DataSource = dt;` binds an additionally datasource to the grid (i think so), instead of clearing the grid.

```
    private void btnClearGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Clear();
        GridView.DataSource = null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `x` after `int x = xxx.MaxValue;` statement? Your explain tell it is total of loop count but I seem that i isn't.

Comment: From your question description above, `i++` only happens in the first run. we may need to see more code.

Comment: x=is just the total number of lines in a file (actually = 129886), which I also use as my collection for the `foreach-loop`. _Could be any value by the way._ But I figured out that the progressBar is working, just very very slow the second the second time I run then `button1_Click-Event`.

Comment: The ReportProgress call is made inside a look controlled by `foreach (var item in collection)`; you've not provided the code which defines `collection`. And you've omitted possibly-relevant code inside this loop.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issue, that was tied to speed of updating ProgressBar, which I solved by adding explicit thread sleep into DoWork method. IE:

```
 b.ReportProgress(i * 100 / x);
 Thread.Sleep(50);
```

(also check 50 milliseconds in this part is not to much comparing to real work being done; if it is report progress & sleep only once in a while)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your progress bar between clicks:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    b.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check for `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` before doing anything, so you don't get `InvalidOperationException` if the `BackgroundWorker` is already running?

Comment: Yes @Bob, u are absolutely right, I'll add that check immediately. Thank you

Comment: @MrMAG Wrap the check around both statements, if you use this, you don't want to reset the progress bar on every click.